# background-image and repeat-x causes image deformation on Mac OS, Firefox 14.0.1

Tags: html, css, macos, firefox

I trying to set background image (pattern) to div and I have a deformation of pattern, that changes while I resize the browser.

- HTML & CSS: http://vulntest.16mb.com/
- Screenshot: https://img.skitch.com/20120830-me47twteijh35i3k2nbkbbadnc.jpg

When I remove repeat-x and set width of the div to pattern width (8px) the image looks ok - img.skitch.com/20120830-m69s2a7x4d3fdxjmsjjs8f58f6.jpg (sorry, can't post more than 2 hyperlinks).
I also tested this code on Windows 7 in IE9, Chrome 21, Firefox 13 and Opera 12.01 and div with repeat-x looks ok.

So my questions are:

1. is that a bug of the browser ?
2. how I can workaround this issue ?

Thanks a lot. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally OK. If you remove the `background-repeat: repeat-x;` then it repeat on both the X and Y axes. Because you gave it a height it can't show you repeat Y. Just remove the `repeat-x;` and give it a larger width. It will repeat on both axes.